# Is there a way to manage spatial files in QGIS as in ArcGIS Manager?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I want to copy and paste shapefiles from one folder to another. Is there a way to do it in QGIS as in ARCGIS Manager and not from the Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is *currently possible* as there was a **feature request** first posted over 4 years ago and only updated 1 year ago:

[Browser: allow renaming, moving and deleting datasources](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4739)